# How to change side-bar font color in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'be been using react-admin and following the guides. I am able to change the background color, the top-bar-menu color and the top-bar-menu font color. I can also change *all* font sizes.

However, I am unable to change the **side-bar-menu font color**. I read a million guides and tried a million methods but absolutely nothing seems to change the side-bar-menu font color. I tried `sx`, `styles`, `theme`, `<Menu /> & <Layout/>`, and more. Also the guides in react-admin's page seem to based on very outdated @mui libraries.

I tried implementing my own `<Menu /> & <Layout/>`, but nothing I did in `sx` or `styles` had any effect on font color.

**Can anyone tell me specifically and clearly how to change the font color of the side-bar-menu in react-admin?**

This is the code that I use to change *other* fonts & colors.

```
export const myTheme = {
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: `#263238` // background color
    },
    primary: {
      main: `#263238`, // has no effect on anything
      contrastText: `#81C784`, // has no effect on anything
    },
    secondary: {
      main: `#263238`, // top-bar color
      contrastText: `#81C784`, // top-bar font color
    }
  },
  typography: {
    fontSize: 25, // affects all text
  }
}
```

In app.tsx; I use `<Admin theme={myTheme} ... ></Admin>`

Other properties of theme seem to have to effect either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to use `palette.text.primary` for that:

```css
export const myTheme = {
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: `#263238` // background color
    },
    primary: {
      main: `#263238`, // has no effect on anything
      contrastText: `#81C784`, // has no effect on anything
    },
    secondary: {
      main: `#263238`, // top-bar color
      contrastText: `#81C784`, // top-bar font color
    },
    text: {
        primary: '#263238',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontSize: 25, // affects all text
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked, I also had to use text.secondary. Could you tell me where do you find that information? So I can read about it more

Comment: I actually search the project source code: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/85e48982957541be7fe1056515188fc9dddddd5c/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/MenuItemLink.tsx#L167